# Boundary fill (flood fill) algorithm to construct an interactive map. Java

Tags: java, swing, dictionary, colors, flood-fill

I am building a US interactive map that will respond to user's input values to the JTable. I have already done this but without flood fill algorithm (each state had its own .png image). Now I have decided to use boundary fill OR seed fill... but it does not work somehow... Here is the FULL code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MapTest extends JFrame {


private static JTable table;
private JTable tableS;
private String[] states = {"US STATES", "Alabama",  "Alaska",   "Arizona"   };
private JLabel map;

private String[][] statesPixel = { {    "alabama",  "300",  "300"   },
        {   "alaska",   "350",  "350"   },
        {   "arizona",  "400",  "400"   },
        {   "arkansas", "450",  "450"   }   };


public MapTest() throws InterruptedException
{
    createMap();
}
private void createMap() throws InterruptedException {
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

contentPane.setSize(1220,700);

tableS = new JTable(4,1);
tableS.setBounds(1000,16,120,800);
tableS.setRowHeight(12);

int i = 0;
while (i < states.length) {
    tableS.setValueAt(states[i], i, 0);
    i++;
}

contentPane.add(tableS);


table = new JTable(4,1);
table.setBounds(1120,16,50,800);
table.setRowHeight(12);
int j = 0;
while (j < states.length) {
    table.setValueAt("100", j, 0);
    j++;
}
table.setValueAt("VALUE",0,0);
contentPane.add(table);

ExcelAdapter excelTable = new ExcelAdapter(table);

map = new JLabel();
map.setIcon(new ImageIcon("map.png"));
map.setBounds(150,50,800,600);
contentPane.add(map);

setTitle("Map");
setSize(1220,700);
setVisible(true);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  //updates~~
   while (true) {
    for ( int k = 0; k < statesPixel.length; k++) {
        int fill = Integer.parseInt( (String) table.getValueAt(k+1, 0));
    boundaryFill4(Integer.parseInt(statesPixel[k][1]),Integer.parseInt(statesPixel[k][2]),statesPixel[k][0],fill+1,0);
    }

}


//*******************************************************************
}

    private void boundaryFill4 (int x, int y, String state, int fill, int boundary) {

       int current;

       current = getPixel (x, y);
       if ((current != boundary) && (current != fill)) {
       setPixel (x, y, fill);
       boundaryFill4 (x+1, y, state, fill, boundary);
       boundaryFill4 (x-1, y, state,fill, boundary);
       boundaryFill4 (x, y+1, state,fill, boundary);
       boundaryFill4 (x, y-1, state,fill, boundary) ;
     }
    }

    private int getPixel(int x, int y) {
    Image img = ((ImageIcon) map.getIcon()).getImage();
    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    int current = buffered.getRGB(x, y);    
    return current;
    }

    private void setPixel(int x, int y, int fill) {
    Image img = ((ImageIcon) map.getIcon()).getImage();
    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    int red = fill;
    int green = red;
    int blue = red;
    Color c = new Color(buffered.getRGB(x, y));
    c = new Color(red, green, blue);
    buffered.setRGB(x, y, c.getRGB());
}

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
MapTest map = new MapTest();
map.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

 }
```

I also use ExcelAdapter.java, which is available online just to enable copy/paste to JTable. How come my code does not work...I have been debugging it... for a long time

Comment: You are using a recursive flood fill algorithm and this will definitely fail for large images. Scanline algorithm is best suited here. Check ***[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)*** page for more info. An implementation of the algorithm can be found ***[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672861/how-to-add-mouseclicked-to-script/14673438#14673438)***

Comment: @Extreme Coders I am familiar with scanline algorithm, however, my problem is: the program does not even show any changes, it is if it ignores my code...The image would load, but no color changes happen AT ALL...BUT I do not get any ERRORs...

Comment: @Extreme Coders There is no problem with ExcelAdapter. I have it as a separate class. It works perfectly. I have already checked it 100% with sysout etc... I have this code written in a different way with ExcelAdapter...

Comment: Debug your code with breakpoints set particularly on the method `boundaryFill4`

Comment: @Extreme Coders   here is the link for Excel Adapter: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/41007907/ExcelAdapter.java

Comment: Also there is no base case in the method `boundaryFill4`, the method recurses indefinitely. You should check whether the current point is within the boundaries of the image, if not the method should return.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever! That's the exclusive task of a LayoutManager maybe related: the while(true) looks fishy, probably blocking the EDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of issues. Actually, as I understand you want to make a test case of a flood fill in order to write some other application. If you are familiar with python, you may find the following to be interesting [Making a weighted USA map based on state-level data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637396/making-a-weighted-usa-map-based-on-state-level-data) There is a ready code, just copy paste it and then you can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Your setPixel method operates on a new BufferedImage, instead of your actual image, so any changes get discarded.

Your boundaryFill4 method also checks for boundaries by seeing if the current pixel is black, which means it will never update any black pixels in the map. Also, since setPixel's changes are discarded, it will never finish (probably).

And lastly, because of your `while (true) {` without any termination condition it's going to just keep looping over all the image pixels endlessly.

Additionally, your code has a few other improvements to be made, such as not creating a new bufferedImage every time you want to get the colour value of a pixel, and indeed switching to an algorithm which doesn't need a stack size of up width+height in the worst case.

Comment: I have been told so. I tried to correct it. But still got errors. Could you please recommend a solution

Comment: You need to modify the image you're displaying. So instead of displaying a png file, load the file into an image object, display that image, then pass that image around to be modified (calling any repaint or update methods if needed, I don't know swing).

Comment: Another option is to just call map.setIcon with your new image every time i.e. `map.SetIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage))`